# Sencha ExtJs 7.1 customize single component

Tags: extjs, components, themes, customization, extjs7

I'm trying to customize a single component CSS, avoid to customize all component.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.tab.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',


    header:{
        xtype: 'myWorkspacesToolbar',
        items:[
             ....
        ]       


    },
    items:[
        ....
    ]
```

I want to customize only HEADER style and his sub items (added dynamically) and not Panel items.
Using scss file myWorkspacesToolbar.scss for example:

```
$button-toolbar-color: #F00;
```

I change all button color (header and panel items and sub items).

Using theme mixing variable I have to set UI for single field in header to obtain CSS changes.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [extjs-button-ui](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#css_mixin-extjs-button-ui) mixin for create needed button and set [ui](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-ui) property to your button in header